# SQL Server can not store Arabic values in the table using sql commands

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have created table and I specifiy the collation to accept Arabic, and it accepts Arabic when I insert or update using SQL Server Edit.

[edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beAej.png)

But when I use the SQL command it shows me (????)

```
    Update  [Imame].[dbo].[Student_data_ex]
 set      [Period] = 'صباحي'      ,[Gender]= 'أنثى'      ,[Email]= '123@hotmail.com'
      ,[Address]= 'سيس'      ,[study_level]= 'ثانوي'      ,[Job]= 'معلم'   
   ,[Work_direction]= 'وزارة '      ,[Job_title]= 'معلم'      ,[department]= 'ممم'  
    ,[Cat]= 'اا'  FROM[Imame].[dbo].[Student_data_ex]  
where[stu_id] = 20180002 




SELECT TOP 1000 [stu_id]
      ,[Period]
      ,[Gender]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Address]
      ,[study_level]
      ,[Job]
      ,[Work_direction]
      ,[Job_title]
      ,[department]
      ,[pic]
      ,[Cat]
  FROM [Imame].[dbo].[Student_data_ex]
```

It returns this:

[by sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uu4k.png)

Comment: Please do not format questions as links.

Comment: What have you tried?  What is your data type in your table for these?  Hint, you can change it to a certain data type and it should work fine.  BUT not for data already in the table.

Comment: Two things need to be correct: **(1)** the column(s) must be of datatype `nvarchar(n)` (specifying a collation on a `varchar` won't work), and **(2)** if you insert Arabic text as string literals in a SQL statement, you ***MUST*** prefix the string literal with a `N` prefix: `INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1) VALUES(N'.....');` to indicate **Unicode** text string

Comment: Was that just the column? What is the server and database collation?

Answer (score 0):

change the output type to "Text" rather than "Grid" on the query editor with CTRL + T shortcut then re-execute query.

[image]